# Why cant I execute a commandlet with arguments from a string in powershell?

Tags: powershell

In windows powershell, I am trying to store a move command in a string and then execute it.  Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
PS C:\Temp\> dir
    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Temp

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         8/14/2009   8:05 PM       2596 sa.csproj
-a---         8/15/2009  10:42 AM          0 test.ps1


PS C:\Temp> $str = "mv sa.csproj sb.csproj"
PS C:\Temp> &$str
The term 'mv sa.csproj sb.csproj' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the
 term and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ &$ <<<< str
PS C:\Temp>
```

I get this error when storing any command with arguments.  How do I overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the help (about_Operators):

```
&  Call operator
  Description: Runs a command, script, or script block. Because the call
  operator does not parse, it cannot interpret command parameters.
```

You can use a script block instead of a string:

```
$s = { mv sa.csproj sb.csproj }
& $s
```

Or you can use `Invoke-Expression`:

```
Invoke-Expression $str
```

or

```
iex $str
```

In contrast to `&`, `Invoke-Expression` *does* parse the string contents, so you can put anything in there, not just a single command.

Comment: Thanks, do you think you can explain (or link to) an explanation of what the & character does?

Comment: `&` is for executing a single command, script or scriptblock, just like the help states. It doesn't do any parsing so it only accepts a single argument which then is assumed to be an invokable command. If you want to add parameters, then either wrap the call in a script or script block or use `Invoke-Expression`. You can find the help page describing the operators by typing `help about_operators` in Powershell.

Answer (score 5):

All of Johannes suggestions are spot on but I want to make folks aware that in V2 there is another option.  You put the command in a string as before but you put the parameters in a hashtable and invoke using & e.g.:

```
$cmd = 'mv'
$params = @{Path = 'log.txt'; Destination = 'log.bak'}
&$cmd @params
```

This uses a new V2 feature called splatting.  It is kind of like using a response file for a command but you put the parameters in a hashtable instead of a file.

Note: you can also put the parameters in an array which will plug in the parameters "by positional" rather than by name e.g.:

```
$cmd = "cpi"
$params = ('log.txt', 'log.bak')
&$cmd @params
```

It may not exactly fit the OP's problem but it is a trick worth knowing about.

Answer (score 2):

I had to answer a similar question a while back about invoking an external program after building up a list of arguments:

> Checked and it looks like using `. $program $argString` or `& $program $argString` does not work if `$argString` contains multiple arguments. The `.` and `&` operators just do a direct call, passing the entire `$argString` as a single argument.
>
> Instead of using `[string]$argString` and doing `` $argString += "-aaa `"b b b`"" ``, you could change it to `[string[]]$argArray` and use `$argArray += @('-aaa', 'b b b')`, which will work and will automatically escape strings as necessary.
>
> You can also use `$process = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start( $program, $argString )`. This will make it easier to track execution progress, but harder to retrieve any text output.
>
> Or you can put everything in a string and use `Invoke-Expression "$program $argString"`, which will parse the entire string as a command and execute it correctly.

As [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282465/why-cant-i-execute-a-commandlet-with-arguments-from-a-string-in-powershell/1288772#1288772) mentioned, splatting is another good option in PowerShell 2.